# Mysql multiple IFNUL or LEFT JOIN, which uses less system resources

Tags: mysql

At the moment i use such query

```
IFNULL(

(SELECT MAX(`AccountCode`) + 1 FROM '. $chart_of_accounts_tn. ' WHERE LEFT(`AccountCode`,3) =  "531" HAVING MAX(`AccountCode`) < "53199"), 

IFNULL( 

(SELECT "531000" FROM '. $chart_of_accounts_tn. ' WHERE LEFT(`AccountCode`,3) =  "531" HAVING MAX(`AccountCode`) = "53199"), 

(SELECT MAX(`AccountCode`) + 1 FROM '. $chart_of_accounts_tn. ' WHERE LEFT(`AccountCode`,3) =  "531" HAVING MAX(`AccountCode`) < "531999") 

)
) AS `MaxValue`
```

i mean, if in mysql highest value with the left three characters "531" is less than "53199", then i need the highest value +1. Else if highest value with the left three characters "531" is "53199" then i need hardcoded value "531000". Else if highest value with the left three characters "531" is less than "531999", then i need the highest value +1.

Possibly such code uses much system resources.

Here is another idea using `left join`

```
SELECT IFNULL(t1.`MaxValue`, IFNULL(t2.`FixedValue`, t3.`MaxValue`)) AS `MaxValue`
FROM (
    SELECT MAX(`AccountCode`) + 1 AS `MaxValue`
    FROM '. $chart_of_accounts_tn. '
    WHERE LEFT(`AccountCode`, 3) = "531"
    HAVING MAX(`AccountCode`) < "53199"
) t1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT "531000" AS `FixedValue`
    FROM '. $chart_of_accounts_tn. '
    WHERE LEFT(`AccountCode`, 3) = "531"
    HAVING MAX(`AccountCode`) = "53199"
) t2 ON 1=1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(`AccountCode`) + 1 AS `MaxValue`
    FROM '. $chart_of_accounts_tn. '
    WHERE LEFT(`AccountCode`, 3) = "531"
    HAVING MAX(`AccountCode`) < "531999"
) t3 ON 1=1
```

Is `left join` better i such situation (uses less system resources)? For example if number of rows in table would be ~ 100 000. May be some other better idea how to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 1):

I think you could achieve the same result using [CASE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html) statement

```
SELECT (CASE 
         WHEN MAX(`AccountCode`) < "53199" THEN MAX(`AccountCode`) + 1
         WHEN MAX(`AccountCode`) = "53199" THEN "531000"
         ELSE MAX(`AccountCode`) + 1
       END) 
       AS `MaxValue`
FROM '. $chart_of_accounts_tn. '
WHERE LEFT(`AccountCode`, 3) = "531"
```